# Tkinter: the search method is showing the wrong data gathered from a csv file

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying to create a functional Product Info Gatherer using csv and tkinter module. So far the searching method works but the data it's getting is wrong for the description.

```
import csv
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

CsvFile = "products.csv"

main = Tk()
main.geometry('500x500')

Entry1 = Entry(main, width = 20)
Entry1.pack()

lbl = Label(main, text = "a")
lbl.pack()
lb2 = Label(main, text = "a")
lb2.pack()
lb3 = Label(main, text = "a")
lb3.pack()

def find():
    with open(CsvFile) as csvcsv:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvcsv)
        barcode = Entry1.get()
        for row in reader:
            if barcode == row['barcode1']:
                for desc, pice in row.items():
                    lbl.config(text = desc)
                    lb2.config(text = pice)
                break
            else:
                lbl.config(text='This Product is currently unavailable')


Button(main, text='search', command = find).place(x=100, y=170)

main.mainloop()
```

I feel like there's something wrong with the lines between 26 to 30( starting from "if barcode" to "break" ) but i couldnt get the right code to make it work.

The csv file looks like this:(since in made this in excel)

```
barcode    desc   pice
1111111    Test   $5.00
```

the code only shows "pice" for lbl and not the "Test" from the desc row. Though the Price shows correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that the `for desc, pice in row.items():` row does what you think it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print out the content of `desc` and `pice` in the inner for loop like below:

```py
for desc, pice in row.items():
    print(desc, pice)
    ...
```

Then you will get the following result in the console:

```
barcode 1111111
desc Test
pice $5.00
```

So the labels `lbl` and `lb2` will be updated with the contents of the last iteration of the for loop, i.e. `pice` and `$5.00`.

Actually you don't need the inner for loop.  Just access the required contents using the column names:

```py
def find():
    with open(CsvFile) as csvcsv:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvcsv)
        barcode = Entry1.get()
        for row in reader:
            if barcode == row['barcode']:
                lbl.config(text=row['desc'])
                lb2.config(text=row['pice'])
                break
        # it is better to use 'else' for the 'for' statement
        else:
            lbl.config(text='This Product is currently unavailable')
```